# Multiple implementation of HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-2.1

Scenario:

> I need to load work items from two project management systems (VSTS and Jira) through their REST API. Each of them has different authorization mechanism:
>
> - VSTS: Using access token that load from database, varied by team/group of users
> - Jira: Using personal token that load from user claims, varied by user

Basic classes and an interface:

```
public interface IProjectManagementClient
{
    ProjectManagementType Type { get; }
    Task<WorkItem> GetWorkItemAsync(ProjectManagement projectManagement, int id, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken));
    Task<List<WorkItem>> GetAllWorkItemsAsync(ProjectManagement projectManagement, string term, int limit = 10, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken));
}

public enum ProjectManagementType
{
    VSTS,
    Jira
}

public class ProjectManagement
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProjectManagementType Type { get; set; }
    public string BaseAddress { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

Setup:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IProjectManagementClient, VstsClient>();
services.AddHttpClient<IProjectManagementClient, JiraClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(provider => new BasicAuthHandler(provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(), CustomClaimTypes.TrackerToken));
```

Usage example:

```
public TimesheetsController(IEnumerable<IProjectManagementClient> projectManagementClients)
{
    _projectManagementClients = projectManagementClients;
}

public void DoWork()
{
    foreach (var timesheet in _timesheets)
    {
        var projectManagementClient = _projectManagementClients.First(o => o.Type == timesheet.ProjectManagement.Type);
        timesheet.WorkItem = timesheet.WorkItemId.HasValue
            ? await projectManagementClient.GetWorkItemAsync(timesheet.ProjectManagement, timesheet.WorkItemId.Value, token)
            : null;
    }
}
```

Issues:

> Even though I've only registered the `BasicAuthHandler` to the `JiraClient`. It has been applied to both VSTS and Jira clients.
>
> Thus it has overridden the VSTS authorization that has been set previously in `VstsClient`.

Both works fine if I only setup and use only of them at a time. Please help.

Comment: Show your realization of ```IProjectManagementClient``` i.e. ```VstsClient``` and ```JiraClient```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JiraClient` gets overriden by `VstsClient` because they are both registered on the same (null) name, which is default. Try to use named registrations:

```
services.AddHttpClient<IProjectManagementClient, VstsClient>("VSTS");
services.AddHttpClient<IProjectManagementClient, JiraClient>("JIRA")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(provider => new BasicAuthHandler(
        provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>(),
        CustomClaimTypes.TrackerToken));
```

In this case `IEnumerable<IProjectManagementClient>` should give two items, configured as above, without override.

Comment: You aren't required to specify name for typed clients. It depends on client realization: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-named-typed-clients-aspnetcore

Comment: @xneg yes, this is another option. However, in order to inject both clients as `IEnumerable<IProjectManagementClient>` one needs names.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Adding the name solves my problem. But I don't think `JiraClient` is overridden by `VstsClient`, they are both injected fine into the example controller.

Comment: @stop-cran: they are NOT registered on the same null name. I kind of explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77492045/2410655. The name is the short name of the interface. In this case, it's `IProjectManagementClient`, which happens to be the same. Hence the `HttpClient` instance on both typed clients is the same instance!

Comment: @stop-cran: also, to be technically correct, `JiraClient` doesn't get overriden by `VstsClient`. They both exist in the DI. You can see them by doing `services.GetServices<IProjectManagementClient>()`. You will get 2 back.