# Add HttpClients with same Interface ended up having the same base url Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a program in ASP.Net Core. I added two `HttpClient` Classes with the same interface on `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public class TypedClientA : ITypedClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public class TypedClientA(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}

public class TypedClientB : ITypedClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public class TypedClientB(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}

// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientA>(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("uri class A");
    });

    services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientB>(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("uri class B");
    });
    ...
}
```

Then I tried calling them in my controller, but the `HttpClient` instance in each typed clients always has the same `BaseAddress`, even though I've filled each with a different base URL during startup.

```cs
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ITypedClient> _typedClients;

    public OtherService(IEnumerable<ITypedClient> typedClients)
    {
        _typedClients = typedClients;
    }
}
```

But, if I do `AddHttpClient` without interface on `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHttpClient<TypedClientA>(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("uri class A");
    });

    services.AddHttpClient<TypedClientB>(httpClient =>
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("uri class B");
    });
    ...
}
```

```cs
public class SomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly TypedClientA _typedClientA;
   private readonly TypedClientB _typedClientB;

   public Class(TypedClientA typedClientA, TypedClientB typedClientB)
   {
      _typedClientA = typedClientA;
      _typedClientB = typedClientB;
   }
}
```

The `HttpClient` on each typed client would have their own `BaseAddress`.

What am I doing wrong? I want each typed client to have the same interface but I also want each `HttpClient` instance inside them to have a different `BaseAddress`. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: In your `Class` do you want to access both classes that implements the `Interface` or just one of them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple implementation of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813805/multiple-implementation-of-httpclient)

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Dependency Injection container works in the way that, when you register multiple dependencies for the same interface, all of them will be registered, and can be resolved through `IEnumerable<IInterface>`. So your first approach won't work in your situation. Your second approach is fine. I don't see any reason to explicitly register them both with your interface.

Answer (score 1):

### Short summary

The `HttpClient` instantiated in each of your typed client is created based on your interface's name, if you just do `.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientImplementation>()`. Hence, the `HttpClient` is the same instance.

And if you have multiple `.AddHttpClient()` configurations in your startup, the last configuration wins. For example,

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientA>(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("address1");
});

services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientB>(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("address2");
});
```

The `HttpClient` instance in both `TypedClientA` and `TypedClientB` is the same instance, whose `BaseAddress` is "address 2" though.

**demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/ldryCt

### Long explanation

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L443) of the extension method `.AddHttpClient()` that takes `<TClient, TImplementaiton>` and an action to configure the Http client, you would notice it's trying to get the name out of `typeof(TClient)`:

```cs
public static IHttpClientBuilder AddHttpClient<TClient, TImplementation>(
    this IServiceCollection services, Action<HttpClient> configureClient)
    where TClient : class
    where TImplementation : class, TClient
{
    ...
    AddHttpClient(services);

    string name = TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName(typeof(TClient), fullName: false);
    var builder = new DefaultHttpClientBuilder(services, name);
    builder.ConfigureHttpClient(configureClient);
    builder.AddTypedClientCore<TClient, TImplementation>(validateSingleType: true);
    ...
}
```

If you continue to look further for the source code of `TypeNameHelper.GetTypeDisplayName`, you can see the name is your interface's name, since it passes `fullName` as `false`:

```cs
public static string GetTypeDisplayName(Type type, bool fullName = true, ...)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    ProcessType(builder, type, new DisplayNameOptions(fullName, ...));
    return builder.ToString();
}

private static void ProcessType(StringBuilder builder, Type type, in DisplayNameOptions options)
{
    if (type.IsGenericType)
        ...
    else
    {
        var name = options.FullName? type.FullName! : type.Name;
        ...
    }
}
```

With that said, for example, if your interface is called `ITypedClient`, doing `typeof(ITypedClient).Name` would give you just `"ITypedClient"`. The full name would give you the name of the interface as well as the namespace.

After getting the name from your interface, the name would be passed to `DefaultHttpClientBuilder`. It just sets its `Name` property to whatever you pass in. [Source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/DefaultHttpClientBuilder.cs) is here.

Next, on `builder.ConfigureHttpClient(configureClient)`([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L28)), the name is used:

```cs
public static IHttpClientBuilder ConfigureHttpClient(this IHttpClientBuilder builder, 
    Action<HttpClient> configureClient)
{
    ...
    builder.Services.Configure<HttpClientFactoryOptions>(builder.Name,
        options => options.HttpClientActions.Add(configureClient));
    ...
}
```

You can see the `name` is continued to be used as the client factory options instance.

Next, if we look at `builder.AddTypedClientCore<TClient, TImplementation>(true)`([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientBuilderExtensions.cs#L368)), there is a method called `AddTransientHelper<TClient>()` call:

```cs
internal static IHttpBuilder AddTypedClientCore<TClient>(this IHttpClientBuilder builder,
    bool validateSingleType)
    where TClient : class
{
    ...
    builder.Services.AddTransient(s => AddTransientHelper<TClient>(s, builder));
    ...
}

private static TClient AddTransientHelper<TClient>(IServiceProvider s, 
    IHttpClientBuilder builder)
    where TClient : class
{
    ...
    HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(builder.Name);
    ...
}
```

Now you can see the `HttpClient` instantiated in each of your typed client is based on the interface's name!

So, if you have multiple typed clients implementing the same interface, you would get the same `HttpClient` instance in each of the typed clients! And that's why you will always get the last setup of the `HttpClient` from your startup, like `BaseAddress`, `DefaultRequestHeaders`, etc.

### Solution

> I want each typed client to have the same interface but I also want each HttpClient instance inside them to have a different BaseAddress. Is there any solution for this?

There is an override for `.AddHttpClient<>()` that takes a name. As long as you supply an unique name for it, each `HttpClient` instance inside of each typed client would be its own instance!

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientA>($"{nameof(TypedClientA)}HttpClient", 
    httpClient => ..);
services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClient, TypedClientB>($"{nameof(TypedClientB)}HttpClient", 
    httpClient => ...);
```

I just picked the name as the name of the typed client implementation, followed by "HttpClient" text, but you're free to use whatever unique name you want.

**demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/4At6V2